# Como listar fecha de inicio y fin de una semana especifica en Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

le comento estoy entrampado con un código, lo que necesito hacer es determinar las fechas de inicio de una semana y la de finalización de la semana de este dia por ejemplo.

Que si estuviésemos el dia 30 de marzo 2023, el dia Domingo seria la fecha 26/03/2023 y la de finalización seria 1/04/2023.

Me podrán ayudar eso es para determinar que si se puede arrendar un articulo

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Rails puedes usar los métodos [beginning_of_week](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-beginning_of_week) y [end_of_week](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-end_of_week).

Comment: Dejame probarlo y te aviso

Answer (score 0):

La solución que di después de mucho investigar y errores fue esta:

```
@first = Date.today.beginning_of_week(:monday).to_date
    @last = Date.today.end_of_week(:sunday).to_date
```

Saludos